# Check if there exists a point in set S1 which is "lower" than a point in set S2 in a D-dimensional space

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Given 2 sets of points S1, S2 in D-dimensional space, how do I efficiently check if there exists a point pair `(a,b)` where `a` is from S1 and `b` is from S2, such that every coordinate of `a` is <= every coordinate of `b`?

I have been struggling to find an algorithm more efficient than the O(n^2 * D) brute-force algorithm which checks every pair (n is the number of elements in S1 and S2).

Comment: Sort by coördinate 1, throw out (stable) sorts by coördinate 2 that case inversions, _etc_? Maybe? This will get you more than you asked for, though.

Comment: Since S1 and S2 are length `n` and each element has  `n` coordinates, it seems like the brute force algorithm is `O(n^3)`, not `O(n^2)`, since the latter would necessarily be optimal.

Comment: You used the same letter n for the dimension of the space and the number of points in each set. Is that intended or a mistake?

Comment: sorry, it's a mistake. I changed the dimension variable from n to d.

Answer (score 1):

The relation between points you described is called ***domination***. It is a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) on the point set, and two subsets of this set can be defined - the subset of minimal points and the subset of maximal points (see definitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements)). So, you can find a ***minimal*** subset for the set `S1` and a ***maximal*** subset for the set `S2`, and then to check every pair of points from these two sets.

Sorry to say, in the worst case you won't get any speedup - this will happen when the set `S1` is equal to its minimal subset, and the set `S2` is equal to its maximal subset. However, in average these minimal/maximal subsets will be much smaller than original sets - so, you *won't check all possible pairs of points* from sets `S1` and `S2`.

The problem of finding minimal/maximal subsets in a D-dimensional point set ("Maxima" problem or "Skyline" problem) is being studied for many years. For example, you can read the section 4.1.3 of the classical [textbook of Preparata and Shamos](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1098-6) to get general understanding about how to approach this problem. Also please take a look at more recent [paper](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2021/13667/pdf/LIPIcs-STACS-2021-22.pdf), where you'll be able to find a good review of this problem history and a number of effective algorithms for it.